# Issue with linking directly to my URL (https://)

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, url, redirect, hyperlink

I've just gotten an SSL cerificate and have redirected my site to display https:// rather than http:// using HTaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.co.uk/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Before I used to link to my index like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.co.uk/">Home</a>
```

And you would be taken to http://www.example.co.uk.

Now with the SSL I've changed it to this:

```
<a href="https://www.example.co.uk/">Home</a>
```

And it is taking me to https://www.example.co.uk/www.example.co.uk/.

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `http -> https` rules should be this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS automatically (only if not in localhost)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```